# Windows does not recognize Sansa Fuze

Tags: mp3-player

I have a Sansa Fuze mp3 player.  When I connect it to my Vista PC, the player itself says "connected" but it does not show up in Windows Explorer or Media Center.

How do I get Windows to recognize the player?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [SanDisk Knowledge Base](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42) article and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating windows mediaplayer, also, make sure to turn the vuze off, then connect.